# Layover at Ataturk Airport for 5 hours

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports

We are totally panicking about our 5 hour layover at Ataturk on the 19th July. We will be flying Turkish airlines and need to stay at the airport for 5 hours till we board our onward flight to Billund, Denmark
No other airline tickets are available.

Is it safe?
Would the airport be affected?

Honest opinions pls!